# How to run javascript function in Razor MVC .net

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
                @if (@Model.Invoice.InvoiceDate != null)
                {

                    <text>
                    function UTCToLocalTime(date) {
                        var time = new Date(Date.parse(date));
                        var timeOffset = -((new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() / 60);
                        time.setHours(d.getHours() + timeOffset);
                        return time;
                    }


                    var date = @Model.Invoice.InvoiceDate
                    UTCToLocalTime(date);
                    </text>




                }
                </script>
```

I am printing the above invoice and its open in a window. I am getting a Unexpected number error.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sequence of numbers is not recognized by JavaScript. If you put it in quotes, it'll be treated like a string instead and be valid:

```
var date = '@Model.Invoice.InvoiceDate';
```

Or, if you want a date object (and have a valid date for it!):

```
var date = new Date('@Model.Invoice.InvoiceDate');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
var date = '@Model.Invoice.InvoiceDate';
```

Since Date.parse is used to parse a string in javascript.

More info about Date.parse [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parse.asp).